# php simple dom parser how to grab iframe from a class

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am having issues getting the correct iframes from a site.

Here is the code i am trying to use. The problem im having is this returns everything in the content class. I would like to return only the iframes that are located in the class. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"User-Agent: User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5\r\n"
)
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$html = file_get_html('http://www.tvshow7.eu/breaking-bad-season-1-episode-1-pilot/', false, $context);

foreach($html->find('.content') as $iframe) {

echo $iframe->outertext, PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Comment: Well since simple DOM's `find` method supports selectors the same as jQuery, couldn't you just do `$html->find(".content iframe")`?

Comment: I tried that but nothing displays.

Comment: Is the iframe inside an element that has the class .content, or does the iframe itself have the class .content?

Comment: The iframe is inside the class .content. Here is the code `<div class="content">
   <p>Breaking Bad Season 1 Episode 1 Pilot<br />
<span id="more-46208"></span></p>
<p><iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=156208734&#038;id=161939590&#038;hash=27804dc57efbce46&#038;hd=1" width="600" height="330" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
<p>Alternative:</p>
<p><iframe src="http://www.putlocker.com/embed/C14AFD42E334072F" width="600" height="330" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>`

Comment: I figured it out. Here the code i used. `// find <p> and store varible
foreach($html->find('p') as $p)

// find iframe from within varibale $p
foreach($p->find('iframe') as $iframe)

echo $iframe->outertext . '<p>';`

Comment: Doubt it will work, but try doing `foreach ($html->find('.content p iframe') as $iframe)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out.

```
<?php
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');


$html = file_get_html('http://www.tvshow7.eu/breaking-bad-season-1-episode-1-pilot/');

// find <p> and store varible
foreach($html->find('p') as $p)

// find iframe from within varibale $p
foreach($p->find('iframe') as $iframe)

echo $iframe->outertext . '<p>';

 // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

?>
```